# Passing a parsed string into a click event handler

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I'm parsing data from an xml file using WebClient. In DownloadStringCompleted method I have a string, which is parsed, that I want to pass into a click event handler. I want the click event to open my app's Marketplace details. For that I need a that parsed string which is a GUID and place it in the event handler. I tried to google it and found nothing. I just can't figure out how to do it.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
public void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) 
    {
        XDocument moreApps = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

        morePageAppList.ItemsSource = from Apps in moreApps.Descendants("App")
                                       select new MoreApps
                                       {
                                           MoreImage = Apps.Element("link").Value,
                                           Price = Apps.Element("price").Value,
                                           Title = Apps.Element("title").Value
                                       };

        var link = (from Apps in moreApps.Descendants("App")
                      select new MoreApps
                      {
                         AppUri = (string)Apps.Element("marketplace").Value
                      }).Single();

        string appLink = link.AppUri;
    }

    private void App_Name_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
        marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = "Marketplace GUID";
        marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
    }
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
morePageAppList.ItemsSource = from Apps in moreApps.Descendants("App")
                                       select new MoreApps
                                       {
                                           MoreImage = Apps.Element("link").Value,
                                           Price = Apps.Element("price").Value,
                                           Title = Apps.Element("title").Value
                                       };

        var link = (from Apps in moreApps.Descendants("App")
                    select new MoreApps
                    {
                        AppUri = (string)Apps.Element("marketplace").Value
                    }).FirstOrDefault();

        appLink = link.AppUri;            
    }

    private void App_Name_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowMarket(appLink);
    }

    private void ShowMarket(string id)
    {
        MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
        marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = id;
        marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Where are you creating your button? If you're giving the button its `Content` via a binding, you could give it a `Tag` of the AppUri.

Comment: How would I use the Tag?

Comment: Inside your click event, var button = (Button) sender; var moreapps = (MoreApps)button.Tag; MessageBox.Show(moreapps.AppUri);

Comment: One more thing I just noticed. You say in your description you're looking to go to your own app's page. If that's actually the case, All you need to do is not set the ContentIdentifier at all.

Comment: Yes that would be the case if I had only one app. I'm making a "More" screen, which has a list of all my apps and I want to parse the info(Links, title, price etc.) from an xml which is on my server. That way I can release new apps and only change the xml instead of making changes to every single app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move your desired functionality *out* of the click handler and add a parameter. That way, you can just call the method and pass in the value `ShowMarket(link.AppUri)`

```
private string appid;

// ..
appid = link.AppUri;
// ..
private void App_Name_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShowMarket(appid);
}

private void ShowMarket(string id)
{

    MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
    marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = id;
    marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
}
```

*edit*: in response to a comment clarifying the question ... all you'd need to do is set link.AppUri to a class property or field, and then in the click handler, simply use that variable to pass to ShowMarket (or however you choose to express the functionality, even right in the click handler)

Comment: Seems like the question is more about accessing the AppUri inside the button event, rather than how to call a function.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Yes willmel is correct. I want to access AppUri in the button event. Eventhough your example works, it takes me automatically to the marketplace. I want the button click to do that.

Comment: that wasn't apparent, not sure a downvote was really called for. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I didn't downvote, someone else did. Anyhow thank you for helping me out!

Comment: now I have small problem. The button takes me to the same marketplace page for every item on the list. How can I make it get the right Uri? I'll update the code above with the current one.

Comment: @AllanHaapalainen that's because you're not referencing a unique element, just the last one. Does your ListBox have buttons? If so, you can handle it using the Tag parameter as I described in the comments.

Comment: my listbox has one hyperlinkbutton that I'm binding the Uris and the titles of the apps to. I started a separate thread about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751845/linq-to-xml-to-parse-multiple-uris-to-a-single-hyperlinkbutton

Comment: @AllanHaapalainen again, guessing you mean your ListBox items EACH have a HyperLinkButton.

Comment: well yeah that's what I meant to say

Answer (score -2):

As I see it there are two ways of doing what you want.

1) Make a class wide variable, aka a field. This can be seen and modified in any of the classes methods. It is a shared variable between the classes methods.

2) Try calling the App_Name_Click method directly passing the variable you want as an object in the sender parameter. ie `App_Name_Click(appLink, new RoutedEventArgs())` or a tidier way is to do this: `App_Name_Click(this, new MyRoutedEventArgs(){GUID = appLink})`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply!